# How does WCF Decide which Operation to Dispatch To?

Tags: wcf, soap, wsdl

I'm building a WCF SOAP application. The WSDL file has numerous operations of which many have the same argument type. The WSDL file defines all soapAction attributes as "''". When I try to start such a service WCF throw an exception saying that soapActions have to be unique.

After some googling I'm even more puzzled than before. I used SOAPUI to create a mock service with two operations which take the same input type and without the soapActions defined it always chooses the same operation. When the actions are defined it works fine.

My questions are:

- Can you make a WCF SOAP service without unique soapActions (actually leaving the soapActions "''" as   defined in the original WSDL)?
- How can a service choose the right operation without the soapAction defined?

Edited: 
I'm not in control of the WSDL. I'm using the WSCF.Blue tool to create a service stub from the WSDL file. I might be able to modify the WSDL, but I want to see if there is some possibility to leave it as it is.

Comment: If you are in control of the WSDL, then you should create unique soapAction values.

Answer (score 2):

It is not very clear from your question but I suggest you are building service based on some defined WSDL, aren't you? WCF by default uses SOAP action because it is required part of WS-I Basic Profile 1.1 offered by WCF services with BasicHttpBinding. WSDLs with empty SOAP actions are used when the action is defined by root body element.

WCF samples provides example of [custom DispatchOperationSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395223.aspx) which is able to route messages to operations by their root body element. This is probably what you need to add to your service so that clients based on provided WSDL can call it.

Comment: Tnx for your answer. The problem is that I don't know how my app could tell which operation to dispatch to even if I use a custom DispachOperationSelector because multiple operations save the same input argument type. I tried creating mock services with SOAPUI, and SOAPUI failed to choose the right operation without the soapAction defined.

Comment: How did you get that web service WSDL?

Comment: Can you also share the name / identification of the standard? Perhaps if you included it in question or title you will get more attention from people who already used it as well.